# Unable to launch instance of my application using subprocess Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance, launch

I have tried the below four ways to launch my application using python and all have failed. Please tell me where I am going wrong. 
As an example, the name of my application is myapp™.exe and is installed in the 
path `"C:\Program Files (x86)\myapp™.exe"`.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="uia").start('myapp™.exe')
dlg_spec = app.myapp™
actionable_dlg = dlg_spec.wait('visible')

from subprocess import Popen
from pywinauto import Desktop
Popen('myapp™', shell=True)
dlg = Desktop(backend="uia").Calculator
dlg.wait('visible')

import os
os.system("open /Applications/myapp™.app")

from subprocess import Popen
Popen(['myapp™'])
```

Comment: 1) SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: In which line you get that error?

Comment: This is the error I am getting

Comment: It is displayed in the command prompt next to the TM symbol

Comment: Sounds like `myapp™` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: The `™` part makes problem, are you using python2?

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.2.

Comment: I then also renamed my app in the installed path and tried without the TM, but still I am faincg the same issue

Comment: I was finally able to launch the application using the 
import subprocess
subprocess.call ('application path')

Comment: However there are a few dll's in the application that are not loaded when i run this script and this causes the application to crash. Any suggestions please ?